# Creating a unique column in SQL Azure Federation

Tags: azure-sql-database, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a unique column in SQL Azure Federation, but even though the following query creates a table, I'm still able to save entries to the table with the same Column1 value. What's the correct way to set up a unique column? I need to make sure ID is the federated uniqueidentifier column whereas, for the purposes of this demo, Column1 cannot have duplicate values.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(
        ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        Column1 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Column2 nvarchar(15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
 (
     ID ASC
 ),
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
 (
     ID ASC,
     Column1 ASC
 )
 ) FEDERATED ON ([dist] = ID)
 GO
```

Comment: Don't really understand the question. Can't you create a unique constraint on Column1.

Comment: This was my original question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416925/create-a-table-with-a-primary-key-and-a-separate-unique-column-in-sql-azure-fede It explains what I'm trying to do. Basically, an ID column needs to be the primary key and an EMAIL_ADDRESS column needs to have a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, can't you do this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(
        ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        Column1 nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Column2 nvarchar(15) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
 (
     ID ASC,
     Column1 ASC
 )
 ) FEDERATED ON ([dist] = ID)
 GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uix_table1_column1 ON Table1(Column1)
GO
```

Then you will have a primary key encompassing the Federation and a separate unique constraint.

Comment: That doesn't work. uix_table1_column1 won't be created because of the following error: "A unique or clustered index on a federated table must contain the federated column." I tried it with ON Table1(ID, Column1). I was able to create the table, but I could still save duplicate values for Column1.

Comment: Please note that ID column must be a primary key whereas Column1 needs to have unique values. So, basically no duplicate values can be saved under each column.

Comment: I would say you are out of luck then. I prefer to manage uniqueness like this in the application layer anyway.